# Only getting Error 500 when trying to load the page

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

Everytime I try to connect to my server i am getting Error messages like these:

GET / 500 47.230 ms - 217

GET / 500 7.858 ms - 217

GET / 500 4.641 ms - 217

As I know it is hard to help without looking at the actual code I uploaded the whole code to github in this 
[Repository](https://github.com/NoobyPilot/TowerDefense-JS)

If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would do that if i knew where in the code the error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Update your package.json!

```
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }
```

2) Then, rename your www.js file to www

3) Add `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the beginning of your `www` file

4) Run `npm start` (it should work)

5) You should also remove .idea folder and add a .gitignore file with ..

```
.idea/
node_modules/
```

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Did what you told me, but it still gives a error in that style... Any other ideas?

Comment: That's weird... I'm only getting 
GET / 500 5.671 ms - 213

Comment: I sent you a pull request 